# Smart speaker using android

Tags: android, voice-recognition

Dear Sir I am Developing a android app in which app automatically set volume of speaker with respect to environment noise.and these all functionality will be perform on voice call e.g after accepting incoming call or after dialing outgoing.Sir internal mic in smartphone will be in use for conversation so i will need external secondary mic  to check noise level. I want to ask that how can i get noise level while on call with external mic parallely to internal mic and which mic is to be Use i will very thankfull to you if you will give me example of any program like that.

I am accessing external mic using below code but don't know how to route voice call to built in mic when call start because due to external mic plunged in call automatically routed to external mic.

Comment: Dear Sir, what did you try? Show us your efforts and we'll tell you what's wrong with it. But if you didn't do your homework, we're not here to do it for you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! 
Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/139399/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.